# postgresql - how to find out which words did not match for IN condition?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query like that (in **postgresql**):

```
SELECT * 
  FROM tablexy 
 WHERE somevalue IN ("<string1>", "<string2>", "<...>", ... )
```

say, `<string1>` is IN somevalue but `<string2>` not. How can I get all the values given in the brackets which are not IN the somevalue column?

thanks ;)

Comment: You need to be more precise what exactly you want

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will probably need a separate query for that. If you have PostgreSQL 8.4 or later, you could use [`unnest`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/functions-array.html) function:

```
 SELECT unnest(ARRAY['<string1>','<string2>', ...]) as element
  WHERE element not in
 SELECT somevalue FROM tablexy
```

Comment: :-( i have 8.3.9 ... and get the error: ::ERROR:  function unset(text[]) does not exist::

Comment: in 9.4.x I get "ERROR:  column "element" does not exist"
until I change it to this format:

 select * from (SELECT unnest(ARRAY['<string1>','<string2>', ...]) as element) as tbl
  WHERE element not in ( SELECT somevalue FROM tablexy )

Answer (score 7):

This solution will work in earlier PostgreSQL versions (at least 8.2) and also faster than Pablo's answer:

```
SELECT listvalue FROM (VALUES ('a'),('b'),('c')) AS list(listvalue)
LEFT JOIN tablexy ON (tablexy.somevalue=list.listvalue)
WHERE tablexy.somevalue IS NULL;
```

In my testing this executes in a millisecond on a table with a million rows if there's an index on `somevalue`, unlike Pablo's which takes seconds.

This might be faster in some cases:

```
SELECT listvalue FROM (VALUES ('a'),('b'),('c')) AS list(listvalue)
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tablexy where somevalue=listvalue);
```

Here's a slow but obvious approach:

```
SELECT listvalue FROM (VALUES ('a'),('b'),('c')) AS list(listvalue)
EXCEPT
SELECT somevalue FROM tablexy;
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I would use an outer join, a RIGHT JOIN in this example:

```
SELECT
    element
FROM
    tablexy 
        RIGHT JOIN (SELECT UNNEST(ARRAY['<string1>','<string2>']) AS element) AS input ON element = somevalue 
WHERE
    somevalue IS NULL;
```

This one can use an index on "somevalue" for performance. Check EXPLAIN to see the queryplan and the usage of an index.